# Posting new field to CustTrans

Tags: axapta, x++

I created a new field in LedgerJournalTrans(General Ledger > General Journals menu), but click on Post  but was unable to get my new field value in the CustTrans, is there any method i need to update to post my new field value to the CustTrans?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I think I can guess what you're trying to do? You've added a field to the table `LedgerJournalTrans` and when you post, you're expecting that data to carry over to the `CustTrans` table? You should work on asking clearer questions, but if my interpretation is correct, then you need to add code so that the posting process *does* something with that field.

Likely you'll need to modify `\Classes\LedgerJournalTransUpdateCust`, specifically you'll want to look at methods `postNewCustomerVoucher` and `updateNow`.

Find where `\Data Dictionary\Tables\LedgerJournalTrans\Fields\CustTransId` gets set, as that's the relation between the two tables, and try to write code that follows that Microsoft is doing.